# Trouble accessing nested JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, rest

I'm trying to get the first name for a customer using americommerce api. I have the following code which works, except when I try to access the `first_name` which returns `KeyError: customer`

since `first_name` is nested under `customer` I'm having problems accessing it.
`order_date` has no problem but when i try what i have currently for `first_name`:

```
 first_name          =result["customer"]["first_name"] or
 first_name          =result["customer"][4]["first_name"] I get an error.
```

I dont understand how to get these nested

```
for result in results['orders']:
          order_status_info= self_api.which_api('order_statuses/%d' % result['order_status_id'])
          for customer_blocked_reason in customer_blocked_reasons:
            if customer_blocked_reason in order_status_info['name']:
              customer_is_blocked = True

          order_id            = 0
          order_date          = result['ordered_at']                
          first_name          =result["customer"]["first_name"] 
          print(first_name)
```

JSON output:

```
    {
        "id": 123,
        "customer_id": 234,
        "customer_type_id": 0,  
        "ordered_at": "2017-01-21T23:19:00-05:00",    

        "billing_address": {
            "id": 123            
        },
        "shipping_address": {
            "id": 443
        },
        "order_status": {
            "id": 1
        },
        "customer": {
            "id": 123,
            "customer_number": "",
            "last_name": "someguy",
            "first_name": "billie",

        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the customer field isn't populated for everyone?

Comment: Try `result["customer"].get("first_name")`, which returns `None` if that field doesn't exist for that customer. Although if you're working with a list of customers, then it would be something like `result[i]["customer"]...`

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that not every order has a `customer` field. So you need to check for that.

```
if 'customer' in result:
    first_name = result['customer']['first_name']
else:
    first_name = 'unknown'
```